# Values are not matching

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in VBA. Here is the question, I'm getting a value from Text box and matching it with a value in the excel sheet. Even though both the values are same, it's showing false. Here is the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim retdata As Variant
    Dim empid1 As Variant

    retdata = TextBox1.Text
    empid1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(retdata + 1, 1)

    If empid1 = retdata Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(retdata + 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A16")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not Found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And what exactly is the value from `TextBox1.Text`? and `empid1`? Step through your code using F8 and check.

Comment: Without knowing the values, how could we possibly know why two values which you think should be the same are treated by VBA as if they were different? Round-off error is a good guess (the number as displayed in a cell is not always the number itself but is instead a rounded version of it) -- but I would rather not guess.  Please give a [mcve]

Comment: I think this is a semantic problem: You use retdata as both a rownumber: .Cells(retdata+1,1) and as an identifier: empid = retdata. So, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things to try:
First, make sure that you are comparing strings with strings. Variants can hold a lot of stuff. Change the if statement to this

```
If CStr(empid1) = CStr(retdata) Then
```

If that doesn't help, then add these lines just before the if statement

```
Debug.Print "*" & retdata & "*"
Debug.Print "*" & empid1 & "*"
```

Bring up the debug window with Ctrl+G and examine the output.